# Numpy error on AWS EC2

Tags: python, numpy

When I try to execute numpy script on AWS EC2, I am getting the following error.

How can I fix this?

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX ~]$ python samplenumpy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "samplenumpy.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

But Numpy is already there on EC2:

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX ~]$ sudo yum install numpy
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates                                             | 2.3 kB     00:00
Package python26-numpy-1.7.2-8.16.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Comment: Your numpy-install is for python 2.6 (so old). I really hope, you are using python 2.7, which would mean there might be still no numpy available for this version!

Comment: use `pip list` to see if `numpy` is actually install in current version.

Comment: Hi Sascha -  [ec2-user@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX ~]$ python --version
Python 2.7.12  as we can see python version of my  AWS AMI is 2.7.12  however when i execute any python script i am using the following command "PYTHON35 sample.py"

Comment: Hi Jenkins Y .. The following command fixed my probelm  ( Installed latest numpy for python 3 )                   
       sudo python3 -m pip install numpy

Comment: I have one question how do i ensure python3 is used by default when i execute a python script ? on aws ec2 ami ? by default its using python 2.7.12  unless otherwise i specify "python35 sample.py" to execute a script

Answer (score 0):

It's a version conflict. **check python version in which numpy is installed**

You need to run your script with same python version in which numpy is installed.

If you are running your code using python2 then install numpy using command:

```
pip install numpy
```

Or if you are running it in python3 then use command :

```
pip3 install numpy
```

To install numpy